# CSS Margins strange behavior

Tags: html, css

I don't understand the following behavior:
[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qa011xhu/)

If I take a `div` and I set the `top` and `bottom margins` and the div has and `height` of `0px`, only the top margin will be used, but if I set the height of the div to 1px all is working right.

[image: Strange behavior]

Why is this happening?

---

### Edit

based on the article cited on @Krzysztof Trzos's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27439948/2931840) I understood that this behavior is based on

> Empty blocks
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-  top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

And in the same article there is written

> Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements **never** collapse.

so to prevent this you can set the `float:left` attribute or `overflow:auto`
(thx to @SW4 for the second)

Comment: I think this is more to do with the lack of `border` in the `height: 0;` `div` rather than the `height` itself.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes - If you set `border:0px` the first example works anyway

Comment: Ignore my original comment, might be worth taking a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing. In particular: **Empty blocks** _If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse._

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here, but the way it's behaving I believe is that if the margin cannot detect anything there then it doesn't have anything to put the margins after or before and therefore they just sit on top of each other. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik - added some additional info for you below

Comment: @SW4 - no, this is not a duplicate, the question that you have linked is a margin collapsing between siblings divs, here is because of an empty block

Comment: @SW4 - why do you say this?

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik - an empty block is a reason behind margin collapsing. The reason / accepted answer has a link with empty blocks as a sub item of margin collapsing. Please have faith!

Comment: @SW4 - yes, same area (margin collapsing) but different causes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `padding` instead of `margin`

http://jsfiddle.net/qa011xhu/1/

I thing the thing with the margin is that it's overlapping on itself. Like it would be if there would be two containers one above another and the first one would have `margin-bottom: 10px;` and 2nd one `margin-top: 10px;`. There would be space 10px between them, not 20px.

And, found this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing

> Empty blocks
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

Comment: I know that it works with paddings, but I would like to understand this behavior

Comment: I think the thing with the margin is that it's overlapping on itself. Like it would be if there would be two containers one above another and the first one would have `margin-bottom: 10px;` and 2nd one `margin-top: 10px;`. There would be space `10px` between them, not `20px`.

Comment: plus one for the article

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [**margin collapsing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

You can overcome it by either using padding, or enforcing a new [**block formatting context**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) on the collapsed element using `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden`

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a
>   Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs
>   and in which floats interact with each other.